# verificaçoes de URL amigavel e ajax

Tags: php, url-amigável

estou com o seguinte problema, fiz uma URL amigavel, porem ela esta dando "conflito" quando uso ajax nos meus forms, quando eu clico em submit, ele duplica meu site, minhas verificaçoes estao assim

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])){

   $url=$_GET['url'];

   $sepURL=explode('/',$url);

}

$diretorio="paginas";

if(empty($sepURL)){

   include_once("$diretorio/home.php");

}elseif(isset($sepURL[0]) && $sepURL[0] == 'classificados' || isset($sepURL[0]) && $sepURL[0] == 'noticias'){

   include_once("$diretorio/class.php");

}elseif(isset($sepURL[0]) && $sepURL[0] == 'contato'){

   include_once("$diretorio/contato.php");

}
```

com essa verificaçao, ele esta duplicando o site quando aperto algum submit que usa ajax no site, alguem sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

caso o parametro url não for especificado ele sempre vai cair na home, já pensou add uma condição nula ? pra caso for especificado uma url nesse campo e ela não estiver predefinida vc verifica se existe um arquivo com esse nome ? assim vc monta callbacks específicos pra suas rotas ajax..

só add no final algo assim essa condição

```
elseif(file_exists($diretorio.$sepURL[0])){

   include_once($diretorio.$sepURL[0]);

}
```

Comment: teria uma funçao pra URL so pegar arquivos que estao dentro do diretorio paginas ? assim creio que ficaria mais facil e simples

Comment: não é isso que você esta fazendo ? então so setar as rotas especificas para as requisições ajax, assim cada arquivo seria respectivo a rota

Comment: nao vai velho `url:"ajax/busca.php",`

Comment: isso é porque você esta pondo o arquivo em outro diretório não ?

Comment: sim, justamente pra nao da conflito entre minhas paginas e o ajax, mesmo assim ele esta duplicando o site, na minha modal com ajax, em vez de abrir o conteudo dela, abre o site inteiro dentro dela, entendeu?